# How can I properly send Authorization Header with Bearer token in Angular Post Request? - "403 Forbidden" - Strapi

Tags: angular, jwt, strapi

I try to make an Angular call to the Strapi API. When I use the same jwt value as passed to this method, I get 200 and new restaurant is inserted into the Strapi DB. But when I use Angular with a code as below I get "403 Forbidden" error:

```
  addRestaurant(restaurant, jwt) {
    const t = 'Bearer ' + jwt;
    const params = {data: restaurant, headers: {Authorization: t}};
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:1337/restaurants', params);
  }
```

Comment: I think this code looks fine,
Can you check that token sent in the request is really the same as provided in your custom Strapi API call? Btw - in future try to use [interceptors for authorization tokens](https://bezkoder.com/angular-10-jwt-auth/#Http_Interceptor)

Answer (score 2):

The headers should be given separately to the data that you want to post.

Post function should be used like [this](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post).

```
this.httpClient.post(url, data, httpOptions);
```

In your case, it should be something similar like that:

```
addRestaurant(restaurant, jwt) {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json',
             Authorization: 'Bearer ' + jwt;
        })
    };
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:1337/restaurants', restaurant, httpOptions);
  }
```